# Getting Exception in deploying on server , How to resolve this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano, cap, sshkit

I am using capistrano to deploy on ubuntu server

Brief Response :

**while executing as ubuntu@planhop.net: invalid encoding**

Logs attached below
Here is detailed response:

```
    ** Invoke staging (first_time)
    ** Execute staging
    ** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
    ** Execute load:defaults
    ** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
    ** Execute rvm:hook
    cap aborted!
```

And:

```
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@planhop.net: invalid encoding
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point::Error: invalid encoding
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/openssl.rb:160:in `initialize'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/openssl.rb:160:in `new'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/openssl.rb:160:in `read_keyblob'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:289:in `read_keyblob'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:248:in `read_key'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:108:in `parse_key'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:75:in `parse_line'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:62:in `block (3 levels) in parse_file'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:60:in `each_line'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in parse_file'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:58:in `open'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:58:in `block in parse_file'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mutex_m.rb:74:in `synchronize'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mutex_m.rb:74:in `mu_synchronize'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:47:in `parse_file'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:18:in `keys_for'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:122:in `block in search_for'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:121:in `map'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh/known_hosts.rb:121:in `search_for'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:96:in `host_keys'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:230:in `prepare_preferred_algorithms!'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:119:in `initialize'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:86:in `new'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:86:in `initialize'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `new'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `start'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:55:in `test'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in '
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
    /Users/shubham.gupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
```

Comment: You should probably ask a question, too.